# Why doesn't "views" work correctly as an MVC route prefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I'm trying to use attribute routing to create a generic action for client-side (specifically AngularJS) templates, so that I don't need a bunch of individual actions for every view.

Here's what I originally tried:

```
[RoutePrefix("views")]
public class ViewsController : Controller
{
    [Route("{area}/{viewName=get}")]
    public ActionResult Get(string area, string viewName)
    {
        return View("~/app/views/" + area + "/" + viewName + ".cshtml");
    }
}
```

Let's say I have a "get.cshtml" view in the folder app/views/home.

What I've noticed is the following:

- If I try to hit `/views/home/get`, it works correctly.
- If I try to hit `/views/home`, I get a 404 and the method never gets executed.
- If I change the controller name to `FooController` (i.e. thought it might be a conflict between convention vs. attribute routing) and try to hit `/views/home`, I **still** get a 404.
- If I remove **all** of the "standard" routes and only use attribute-based routing, I still get a 404. So it definitely doesn't seem to be a conflict.
- If I change it to `[RoutePrefix("view")]` and try to hit `/view/home`, it **does** work correctly.

Why does this happen? Is it a bug in the attribute routing? Is it some kind of special keyword or reserved word in MVC routing? Does it have something to do with the default MVC "views" folder, which still exists with its web.config and so on?

Comment: View is keyword for representing Views(.aspx/.cshtml) UI element. Controller's Action method will call View() method to return UI

Comment: @malkam: I'm quite aware that there's a method of the `Controller` class called `View`. It wouldn't be possible to build even the most basic of MVC apps without it. Nevertheless, I fail to see how that's relevant here.

Comment: I don't think there's any documentation about it but Views seems to be some sort of reserved word. It probably has to do with the folder named `Views` as per the MVC convention

Comment: You have the exact problem I do, your application sees /Views/Home as a folder and /Views/Home/Get as an action in a controller. I sure wish to see a resolution for this conflict.